# Check a large group of checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I want to be able to say:

Get the first textblock, then the first checkbox, both with the number 1 in their name.

Then if the checkbox is checked, then the textblock can be populated.

See code:

```
     for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {

            TextBlock a = (this.FindName(string.Format("tb_{0}", i)) as TextBlock);
            CheckBox b = (this.FindName(string.Format("ck_{0}", i)) as CheckBox);
            if (b.IsChecked.HasValue)
            {
            if (a != null) a.Text = data.ArrayOfSensors[i].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (a != null) a.Text = data.ArrayOfSensors[0].ToString();
            }

        }
```

So when the checkbox is enabled, the textblock will be populated with the index from the array.

Many thanks!

EDIT: A slightly better explanation:

The textblocks are named: tb_1, tb_2 etc

The Checkboxes are named: cb_1, cb_2 etc

The array is:

[0]  0

[1]  100

[2]  150

The number is what they all have in common. So I can use a for loop with i as a common variable for each. I also have about 50 textboxes and Comboboxes and don't want to write each one out individually.

EDIT: My ComboBoxes and Textblocks are created on Xaml code  like this:

```
   <CheckBox x:Name="Cb_1" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="349,53,127,164" IsChecked="True" />

   <TextBlock x:Name="tb_1" Text="80" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="266,35,205,177" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Get the first textblock, then the first checkbox, both with the number 1 in their name. in your question" ?

Comment: And what goal of such crazy things? :)

Comment: Added edit for you guys! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its hard to answer without seeing what your XAML looks like, however it sounds like you may be trying to use WPF like it is WinFirms.

To build an interface like this in WPF, you should start by creating a custom class to hold your data, and then use an `ItemsControl` to render your collection of data.

For example, your class might look something like this

```
public class SensorData() : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // should implement INotifyPropertyChanged of course
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

And an `ObservableCollection<SensorData>` might be rendered using an `<ItemsControl>` with a `ItemsPanelTemplate` containing both a `CheckBox` and a `TextBox`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionOfSensorData}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Checked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This will loop through the collection of `SensorData` objects, and render a CheckBox and TextBox for each one. If you want to do any manipulation of the data from the code-behind, you only need to modify the properties of the `SensorData` objects.

For example, you could have a loop that goes

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyCollectionOfSensorData.Length; i++)
{
    SensorData item = MyCollectionOfSensorData[i];

    if (item.IsChecked)
        item.Text = data.ArrayOfSensors[i].ToString();
    else
        item.Text = "0";
}
```

And there would be no interaction with the UI objects at all.

Comment: I haven't done it that way. I've generated a random number which then populates the array. From there, it then feeds it into the ui. See edit! :)

Comment: @TomPitts I'm not sure I understand the question. I did another modification to my answer after posting it (does not show up in edit history because it was under 5 minutes) - can you review the updated answer and let me know if that helps you out? I think my answer would still be the same

Comment: @TomPitts as Rachel said, you are trying to use WPF like WinForms... It's not good.

Comment: For this project I have to use WPF. I just want an easy way to say, if both the textblock and combobox name ends in a 1 and the combobox is checked, then the textblock displays text from array position[1]. wrap this in a for loop so that I can run it through each textblock and combobox, so 2 would be next, and so on for each position in the array.

Comment: @TomPitts What's wrong with the code you have posted for that? I think it should do what you're looking for. That said, that's not the correct way to do things in WPF, and it would be better if you could abstract your data rather than working directly with the UI objects like that :)

Comment: @Rachel I think the problem is that I'm searching for a checkbox name with "cb_". The line: CheckBox b = (this.FindName(string.Format("ck_{0}", i)) as CheckBox);  Actually returns a true, not a checkbox name that I can use to check if it is checked.

Comment: @Tom `this.FindName` should search the Visual Tree for an element with the specified name, and return it. So if you have `<CheckBox x:Name="ck_1" />` then `this.FindName("ck_1")` should return you the CheckBox object, not a boolean value. That CheckBox object can be assigned to a variable (`b` in your code), and you can treat the variable `b` as if it were a CheckBox, and call `b.Checked` to find the checked value. It would really help if you could edit your question to include how your TextBoxes/Checkboxes are created though, or perhaps explain what exactly is wrong with the posted code.

Comment: @Rachel So something like: var b = (this.FindName(string.Format("cb{0}", i)));  ?

Comment: @TomPitts `.FindName` returns a datatype of `object` by default, so you want to cast that to a `CheckBox` to access CheckBox-specific properties. The syntax used in your question's code (`CheckBox b = (this.FindName(string.Format("ck_{0}", i)) as CheckBox)`) means "create a variable of type CheckBox, call it `b`, and attempt to parse the result of `.FindName` into it. If this parse fails, assign it a value of null". Typically you should always check that `b != null` before using it to avoid a `NullReferenceException` as well

Comment: @TomPitts Glad that worked out for you~ If you do continue to program in WPF though, I would highly recommend learning the MVVM design pattern to go along with it. It is the standard for WPF development, and makes coding and maintenance much easier :)